# Styles from bootstrap and global.scss are overriding on NEXT JS 13.4.1 when building for production

Tags: next.js, sass, bootstrap-5, production-environment, next.js13

This problem just occurs when building for production, in development the styles are showing ok.

the bootstrap styles aren't applying at all, just the styles on the main.scss are working. I couldn't find any example code using the app router + bootstrap + scss.

**This is the file structure:**

```
**/app
--/css**
----main.min.css
----main.min.css.map
**--/scss**
----_fonts.css
----_header_footer.scss
----_mixins.scss
----_responsive.scss
----main.scss
--layout.jsx
```

**In the main.scss the imports are:**

```
@import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
 @import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
 @import "nouislider/dist/nouislider.min.css";
 @import "@splidejs/splide/dist/css/splide.min.css";
 @import "_mixins";
 @import "_header_footer";
 @import "_fonts";
```

**In the layout.jsx (the RootLayout):**

```
  import './css/main.min.css'
```

On development all the styles applies perfectly, only after building I have the problem that the bootstrap classes on the jsx throughout the app are not working.

**I have tried adding this import to the layout.jsx file:**

```
 import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

With this the bootstrap styles work on build, but some of my scss styles go down, for example the font applied to the body and the text decoration none for anchor tags, to  name a few.

**I've also tried this:**

Add the following code to _app.js:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import '../styles/globals.css';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

**I've also tried creating a global.scss file on the /app root and there importing the bootstrap.min.css and my main.min.css:**

**I've also tried moving the import of the boostrap.min.css way down in my main.scss file, also omiting the 'min' on the imports**

Answer (score 1):

Create a page pages/_document.js

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head>
        <link
          rel='stylesheet'
          href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
        />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

Remove bootstrap CSS import from _app.js

[image]